# Natural definition of morphism between two structures

Tags: category-theory

I have a general questions about category theory (I don't know many things about this area, so please, be indulgent if these questions are a bit fuzzy)

1) If we consider for example the class of groups and two groups $(G, +)$ and $(H, ×)$. We will say that $f : G \rightarrow H$ is a morphism if : $\forall (x, y) \in G \times G, f(x + y) = f(x) × f(y)$, right ? But why is that so ? I mean, why this definition of morphism between groups is admitted and not another one ?

2) If we want to consider a new kind of class, how can we find a "natural" definition of morphism between two structures of this class ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can make different choices. You could, for example, consider the category with objects that are groups, but just plain functions as morphisms. This is a category. It's a bit pointless because the group structure is just ignored, but it satisfies all the laws. There are all kinds of other options as well, e.g. you could have an arrow if and only if one group is a subgroup of the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If, for example, you would just discover the group structure now and you would not know anything about the classical definition of group morphism, is there a way to find naturally this classical definition knowing a bit of category theory ?

Comment: Not knowing just category theory (unless you discovered this notion of groups via categorical constructions, e.g. Lawvere theories). The class of objects does not determine the morphisms. There are plenty of frameworks for defining broad classes of things which can be formulated categorically and will provide *a* notion of morphisms, usually a good one. In general though, category theory operates on categories and morphisms are part of the data of a category, so to start turning the cranks of category theory, you need to have already said what the morphisms of the relevant categories are.

Comment: Okay, I understand better... could you give me an example of these frameworks (or references) ?

Comment: I've mentioned one, [Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) which can be generalized in various ways, but even the basic form covers and generalizes almost all of universal algebra and is fairly accessible. [Categories of (pre)sheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+sheaves) covers many other examples. Both of these have objects be functors and arrows natural transformations. (For groups in particular, you can notice that they are essentially one object categories where all arrows are isomorphisms, so group theory is technically part of category theory.)

Comment: Perfect, I will look at these frameworks. Thank you again !